# Why is this LINQ query not returning the correct dates?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0

The following LINQ query reads a delimited file and returns the most-recent record for each recordId. The problem is, the most-recent record is not always returned. What am I doing wrong? What do I need to change to ensure the most-recent date is always returned? Is there a better way than using .Max()?

I've also attached some sample data so you can see the issue. When looking at the sample data, the rows marked with an asterisk (*) are the rows I want returned (the most recent date). The rows marked with an X are what gets incorrectly, in my opinion, returned.

In cases where the same recordId appears multiple times (#162337, for example) and has multiple dates, I want one record returned with the most-recent date.

```
var recipients = File.ReadAllLines(path)
    .Select (record => record.Split('|'))
    .Select (tokens => new 
        {
        FirstName = tokens[2],
        LastName = tokens[4],
        recordId = Convert.ToInt32(tokens[13]),
        date = Convert.ToDateTime(tokens[17])
        }
    )
    .GroupBy (m => m.recordId)
    .OrderByDescending (m => m.Max (x => x.date ) )
    .Select (m => m.First () )
    .OrderBy (m => m.recordId )

    .Dump();


FirstName   LastName    recordId    date    
fname   lname   137308  2/15/1991 0:00  
fname   lname   138011  6/16/1983 0:00  *
fname   lname   138011  11/9/1981 0:00  x
fname   lname   158680  9/4/1986 0:00   
fname   lname   161775  4/23/1991 0:00  
fname   lname   162337  12/1/1998 0:00  *
fname   lname   162337  12/1/1998 0:00  *
fname   lname   162337  9/1/1994 0:00   x
fname   lname   162337  9/1/1994 0:00   x
fname   lname   163254  2/12/1969 0:00  
fname   lname   173816  9/26/1997 0:00  
fname   lname   178063  1/16/1980 0:00  *
fname   lname   178063  3/3/1976 0:00   x
fname   lname   180725  7/1/2007 0:00   *
fname   lname   180725  1/14/1992 0:00  x
fname   lname   181153  5/1/2001 0:00
```

Answer (score 5):

You're ordering the entire sequence of groups by the maximum date within each group. What you need to do is order *within each individual group* so that only the item with the maximum date is selected.

```
var recipients = File.ReadAllLines(path)
                     .Select(record => record.Split('|'))
                     .Select(tokens => new
                         {
                             FirstName = tokens[2],
                             LastName = tokens[4],
                             recordId = Convert.ToInt32(tokens[13]),
                             date = Convert.ToDateTime(tokens[17])
                         })
                     .GroupBy(m => m.recordId,
                              (k, g) => g.OrderByDescending(m => m.date).First())
                     .OrderBy(m => m.recordId);
```

If performance is important and each group could potentially contain many items then you *might* see a slight improvement if you use `Aggregate` to determine the max record in the group rather than the `OrderByDescending`/`First` combo:

```
// ...
.GroupBy(m => m.recordId,
         (k, g) => g.Aggregate((a, m) => (m.date > a.date) ? m : a))
// ...
```

Comment: Wow - I didn't know GroupBy had an overload for a result selector that operated on the entire group.  Nice

Comment: Aggregate edit is even cooler.  Thanks for teaching me two things today +1

Comment: I tried the three suggestions offered here (LukeH's and Adam Rackis's). All perform about the same, execution time is 6.5 seconds for a sample file with 10,000 records. @LukeH, thanks for your suggestion. I'll need to dig into it more to fully undertand what's going on.

Comment: I ran some tests using real production data in VS2010 (instead of LinqPad - 6.5 seconds / 10,000 ) and the execution time ranged from 188-260 milliseconds for all three suggestions. In my scenario, there was no significant difference when processing 30,000 records.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that this line:

```
.OrderByDescending (m => m.Max (x => x.date ) )
```

is sorting the *groups* by what their max date is, rather than the items in each group?

This trimmed-down code segment appears to produce the results you're looking for (though you'd have to work it in with your file-processing, obviously)

```
        List<Customer> Customers = new List<Customer>() {
            new Customer(){ RecordId = 12, Birthday = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)},
            new Customer(){ RecordId = 12, Birthday = new DateTime(1982, 3, 22)},
            new Customer(){ RecordId = 12, Birthday = new DateTime(1990, 1, 1)},

            new Customer(){ RecordId = 14, Birthday = new DateTime(1960, 1, 1)},
            new Customer(){ RecordId = 14, Birthday = new DateTime(1990, 5, 15)},
        };

        var groups = Customers.GroupBy(c => c.RecordId);
        IEnumerable<Customer> itemsFromGroupWithMaxDate = groups.Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(c => c.Birthday).First());

        foreach(Customer C in itemsFromGroupWithMaxDate)
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1}", C.RecordId, C.Birthday));
```

Or better yet:

```
IEnumerable<Customer> itemsFromGroupWithMaxDate = Customers.GroupBy(c => c.RecordId).Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(c => c.Birthday).First());
```

Taking a blind stab at your code, I believe this might work:

```
var recipients = File.ReadAllLines(path)
    .Select (record => record.Split('|'))
    .Select (tokens => new 
        {
        FirstName = tokens[2],
        LastName = tokens[4],
        recordId = Convert.ToInt32(tokens[13]),
        date = Convert.ToDateTime(tokens[17])
        }
    )
    .GroupBy (m => m.recordId)
    .Select(m => OrderByDescending(x => x.date).First())
    .OrderBy (m => m.recordId )

    .Dump();
```

Comment: Yup, that's it. That line is sorting the groups using each groups maximum date. So, now how do I fix it?

Comment: So far, and with limited testing, your "blind stab" is producing the expected values. Thank you very much!